# Python SSL Error , Server side - Client certificate verify failing with Intermediate cert - self-signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1007)

Tags: python-3.x, ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate

I'm using an intermediate certificate to sign the client certificates,

while trying to enable client certificate validation on server side using python 3.10 with following code

```
ssl_context = ssl.create_default_context(purpose=ssl.Purpose.CLIENT_AUTH)
ssl_context.load_cert_chain(certfile=settings.CERTS_TLS_SERVER_CERT,
                                    keyfile=settings.CERTS_TLS_SERVER_KEY,
                                    password=settings.CERTS_TLS_SERVER_CERT_PASSWORD)
ssl_context.load_verify_locations(cafile=settings.CERTS_CA_CERT)

ssl_context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_REQUIRED
```

but this is throwing the following error while client connect

Error

```
transport: <asyncio.sslproto._SSLProtocolTransport object at 0x7f657f115fc0>                                                                                                                             │
│ Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                                                                       │
│   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 213, in _accept_connection2                                                                                                          │
│     await waiter                                                                                                                                                                                         │
│   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/asyncio/sslproto.py", line 534, in data_received                                                                                                                       │
│     ssldata, appdata = self._sslpipe.feed_ssldata(data)                                                                                                                                                  │
│   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/asyncio/sslproto.py", line 188, in feed_ssldata                                                                                                                        │
│     self._sslobj.do_handshake()                                                                                                                                                                          │
│   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/ssl.py", line 975, in do_handshake                                                                                                                                     │
│     self._sslobj.do_handshake()                                                                                                                                                                          │
│ ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self-signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1007)
```

The Client context

```
context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS_CLIENT)
context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_REQUIRED
context.load_verify_locations(cafile='certs/generated/ca.crt')
context.load_cert_chain(certfile="certs/generated/client.crt",
                            keyfile="certs/generated/client.key")
```

I verified

- CA cert availability in server SSL context, ca cert containing both Root CA and Intermediate CA
- Set `ssl_context.verify_flags = ssl.VERIFY_X509_PARTIAL_CHAIN`

No luck

Any idea why this error happening?

Comment: But what is the client *sending*?

Comment: @user207421 Added client SSL-context to question

Comment: The server cannot validate the certificate of the client. It is unclear how the client.crt sent refers to settings.CERTS_CA_CERT. Please provide a more complete example where you not only have the code but the actual content of the certificate and CA files - or show how they can be reproducible created.